# How to set magit recent commit always expand when i open magit status?

Tags: magit

When I open a Magit status buffer, then the recent commit section is closed, I need to use `TAB` to expand it. How can I configure it to always be expanded.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The option `magit-section-initial-visibility-alist` can be used to configure this.

First you have to figure out the sections type using `M-x magit-describe-section-briefly` while point is on the section in question.

That shows `#<magit-section "@{upstream}.." [unpushed status] 372-935>`, so the type is `unpushed`, which is a bit surprising. The "Recent commits" section is actually just the form that the `Unpushed to @{upstream}` takes when there aren't actually any commits that haven't been pushed to `@{upstream}`.

To set the initial visibility use:

```
(setf (alist-get 'unpushed magit-section-initial-visibility-alist) 'show)
```

`magit-section-initial-visibility-alist` only supports setting the visibility based on the type (as opposed to also taking the value (here `"@{upstream}.."`) into account). There can be a second section of type `unpushed`: `Unpushed to <push-remote>`. Given the above setting, that is also expanded initially.

Comment: thanks for your reply. its very useful.